# How do I get table names in intellisense under Visual Studio 2012 Database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, database-project

We have recently moved our source control for stored procedure and function SQL files from VSS integrated with SSMS to a Database project under Visual Studio 2012. This has enabled us to easily integrate with TFS, which was our ultimate goal.

Under VSS with SSMS, we could see table names, function names, views, etc as we typed. But under Visual Studio 2012, we've noticed that Intellisense no longer knows these specific names. It does know database names and roles, so we know it is connected to the database at some level.

Is there an easy way to enable this functionality again? I've looked online, and I don't see many other people experiencing this issue/situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, although it wasn't exactly what we were hoping for. We would like for VisualStudio to get the Schema information straight from the database. (The SQL files in our project were just for views and stored procedures). However, when we imported our table and functions into the project, it used that information to build the intellisense.

The good news is that we found a solution. The bad news is that when processes outside of our DB project alter some of the tables (we have a few that do this), then we have to remember to refresh those schemas in our project before intellisense will work properly.

**Side note:** here's a quick way to import your tables, functions, etc. especially when you have to do refreshes on said objects occasionally like we will have to do.

Before you get started, determine what kind of object you are going to be exporting from your database: Tables, Stored Procedures, Views or Functions. Create a folder under your DB project for each item that you want to export.

In SSMS, open the database server and right-click on the database instance you want to work with. Go down to Tasks -> Generate Scripts ... From there, select specific database objects. In this example, want to extract JUST the tables. Select "Tables", and leave all others unchecked, then click Next.

On this screen, select "single file per object", and give it a path to your "Tables" sub folder under your database project. I prefer to have my scripts DROP and CREATE instead of ALTER, so click "Advanced" and change create mode to "DROP and CREATE".

From here, just "Next" your way out of all of the dialogs. BOOM! You now have a series of SQL files that you can include in your project. These SQL files will enable intellisense to work properly, and you have a launchpad for generating all of your database objects without having to rebuild them all from scratch.